# How to receive a string as a return from an API call in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http

I need to get response from my API call in form of string.
My API function is simple (for testing)

```
        [HttpPost("verifyCode")]
        public ContentResult verifyCode([FromBody] UserM resetModel)
        {
            return "This is response";
        }
```

API Call

```
verifyCode(username, code){
      const body = 'username=' + username + '&code=' + code;
       let test = new UserM();
       test.username = username;
       test.code = code;
       const requestHeaders: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      });
      return this.http.post<string>('http://localhost:12763/api/account/verifyCode/', test, {headers: requestHeaders, withCredentials: true});
    }
```

i am trying to get the output here

```
 this.userService.verifyCode(username,code).subscribe(
        (data)=>{
          console.log(data);
        }
      )
```

But i dont get the output on console but get this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'` doesn't ring a bell to you ?

Comment: I removed the header but it shows the same error

Comment: Which HTTP service are you using, HTTP or HttpClient ?

Comment: I am using httpClient

Answer (score 0):

Change your backend response and try it will be work

```
[HttpPost("verifyCode")]
public ContentResult verifyCode([FromBody] UserM resetModel)
{
    return ContentResult ("This is response","text/plain",Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: It shows the error of "ContentResult" cannot be used as a method

Comment: try this >> var result = new ContentResult();
result.Content = "Text"; or  ContentResult result = new ContentResult
                                {
                                    Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response),
                                    ContentType = "application/json",
                                    ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
                                }; return result;

Comment: @Umer this error because of back-end try another way to send response

Comment: use this in my API?

Comment: i just need to send back a string message. Can you suggest me any better way?

Comment: change return type of verifyCode method to string check whether it will work or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193277/discussion-between-kgdc-and-umer).